# How much JavaScript can actually be loaded into memory by a browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I'm working on a BIG project, written in RoR with jQuery frontend. I'm adding AngularJS which has intelligent dependency injection, but what I want to know is how much javascript can I put on a page before the page becomes noticeably slow? What are the specific limits of each browser?

Assuming that my code is well factored and all operations run in constant time, how many functions, objects, and other things can I allocate in javascript before the browser hits it's limit (which there must be one, because any computer has a finite amount of RAM and disk space (although disk space would be an ambitious limit to hit with javascript)

I've looked online but I've only seen questions about people asking how many assets they can load, i.e. how many megabytes can I load etc. I want to know if there is an actual computation limit set out by browsers and how they differ

-- EDIT --

For the highly critical, I guess a better question is

> How does a modern web browser determin the limit for the resources it allocates to a page? How much memory is a webpage allowed to use? How much disk space can a page use?

Obviously I use AJAX, I know a decent amount about render optimization. It's not a question of how can I make my page faster, but rather what is my resource limitation?

Comment: Browsers don't enforce fixed limits on resources. That would be silly.

Comment: This is truly a per machine/browser situation. I would recommend not going over 512 MB of expected usage unless necessary as this will probably tap out many computers that are still 32-bit. Otherwise, I have seen and used webpages that load over 1 GB of code over time that ran just fine.

Comment: good luck laying angular on top of jQuery app  ... big design red flag. Better off doing a rewrite in angular

Comment: Could have 100,000 lines of script that has  less memory use than 10,000 lines. Apples to oranges comparison without considering what the script is doing

Comment: @SebastianNette it can **certainly** be answered. I think you mean to say that there isn't one single right answer, but rather a set of them

Comment: @KennethSalomon can you please point to an example of a site using "over 1GB of code"

Comment: @BrianWheeler I cannot explicitly do that. It's an internal website at work that uses about 250MB on load and the more you scroll around and retrieve information, the more RAM it will take. It is not pure JavaScript taking up the RAM though.

Comment: @charlietfl very true. you could also try and recursively find fibonacci numbers without optimization, and that would put you underwater with less than 20 lines of code. My question is when does it put you underwater? After using a GB of ram? 60% of system memory? Where is the hard stop before the page and/or browser crashes?

Comment: Question is better suited for other stackexchange site like superusers since it's really not a programming question. Lots of hardware and operating system implications, not just browsers involved

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your opinion about Angular on top of jQuery. I am doing a rewrite in angular and removing the old jQuery code, but you should know that AngularJS actually ships with a slimmed down version of jQuery built in. Not at all a design red flag to use both, but it must be done appropriately

Comment: right...the critical part of that statement (and lots try it) was putting angualr on top of existing code base rather than sprinkling jQuery in on an as needed basis. See it all the time here..."why doesn't my document.ready code work in angular view"

Answer (score 2):

Although technically, it sounds a monumental task to reach the limits of a client machine, it's actually very easy to reach these limits with an accidental loop. Everyone has done it at least once!

It's easy enough to test, write a JS loop that will use huge amounts of memory and you'll find the memory usage of your PC will peg out and will indeed consume your virtual memory too, before the browser will fall over.

I'd say, from experience, even if you don't get anywhere near the technological limits you're talking about, the limits of patience of your visitors/users will run out before the resources.

Maybe it's worth looking at AJAX solutions in order to load relevant parts of the page at a time if loading times turn out to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to minify and package your javascript to reduce initial page requests as much as possible. Your web application should mainly consist of one javascript file when you're all done, but its not always possible as certain plugins might not be compatible with your dependency management framework.

I would argue that a single page application that starts to exceed 3mb or 60 requests on an initial page load (with cache turned off) is starting to get too big and unruly. You'll want to start looking for ways of distilling copy-and-pasted code down into extendable, reusable objects, and possibly dividing the one big application into a collection of smaller apps that all use the same library of models, collections, and views across all of them. If using RequireJS (what I use) you'll end up with different builds that will need to be compiled before launching any code if any of the dependencies contained within that build have changed.

Now, as for the 'speed' of your application, look at tutorials for render optimization for your chosen framework. Tricks like appending a model's view one-by-one as they are added to the collection results in a faster rendering page then trying to attach a huge blob of html all at once. Be careful of memory leaks. Ensure you're closing references to your views when switching between the pages of your single page application. Create an 'onClose' method in your views that ensures all subviews and attached data references are destroyed when the view itself is close, and garbage collection will do the rest. Use a global variable for storing your collections and models. Something like `window.app.data = {}`. Use a global view controller for navigating between the main sections of your application, which will help you close out view chains effectively. Use lazy-loading wherever possible. Use 'base' models, collections, and views and extend them. Doing this will give you more options later on for controlling global behavior of these things.

This is all stuff you sort of learn from experience over time, but if enough care is taken, it's possible to create a well-running single page application on your first try. You're more likely to discover problems with the application design as you go though, so be prepared to refactor your code as these problems come up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends much more on the computer than the browser - a computer with a slow CPU and limited amount of RAM will slow down much sooner than a beefy desktop.

A good proxy for this might be to test the site on a few different smartphones.

Also, slower devices *sometimes* run outdated and/or less feature-rich browsers, so you could do some basic user-agent sniffing or feature detection on the client and fall back to plane server-rendered HTML.